# Check if Paypal-Payment is pre-authorized

Tags: api, paypal

can i check if the paypal-payment is preauthorized by the user?
If my User select Paypal for payment, i redirect him to Paypal-Site.
The User logs in, and the he authorizes the payment and then paypal redirects the user back to the shopping cart to review the order and finish it by pressing the order button.
Then i do the ApiCall "DoExpressCheckout".

Everything is fine.

But if the User logs in into his Paypal-Account and then click "Cancel" he is redirected to the Shopping-Card and if he then press the Order-Button, i get the Error "Payment not authorized by User".

My question now: Can i check, if the Payment was successfully "Pre"-Authorized by User?
I got the PayerID, i got the Status "Ack=Success", but i dont know if the User really has authorized the payment, right?

Best Regards,
Michael

Answer (score 1):

If you call [DoExpressCheckoutPayment](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoExpressCheckoutPayment_API_Operation_NVP/) and it comes back with `ACK=Success` then you got paid (although the payment could take a few days to clear in some cases). There is no "pre-authorized" state that I know of (unless you mean Billing Agreements but those simply let you run DECP without having the user do a full checkout again).

If they cancel after you call [SetExpressCheckout](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/) then you shouldn't get any notices. Paypal will redirect them to your `CANCELURL` url.